# Rainbow square and influences of disable_splash=1 (or: how to get rid of the colored square)

Tags: boot, raspi-config, firmware

I am currently working with a small Raspberry Pi Model A setup (and want to stick at this model until I can grab a model Zero). It was modified to be as quiet (aka black) on boot as possible which works fine.

So far there is a custom created service starting a video with the hello video demo on boot. Even that works fine and the video is playing nicely.

The problem is I want to get rid of the colored rainbow square on boot because it is the last ugly experience. There is the option to set disable_splash to 1.

But this not only results in a not shown splash screen but also in making the video shown flickering (black diagonal stripes moving over the screen).

What are the detailed influences of disable_splash and how can I get rid of the colored square (disabled or tainted black) while keep the video playing nicely?

---

Here are only the lines of config.txt which are not commented out

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0
display_rotate=1
config_hdmi_boost=0
gpu_mem=96
disable_splash=1
```

Comment: `disable_splash=1` should work alright. Not sure why it is not working. May be you can edit your question and include your `config.txt` so that others can have a look at it.

Comment: added the modified lines of the config. I tested it on different tiny touch screens in portrait mode (that's why display is rotated) with the same effect,

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=86781 Have a look at this thread.

Comment: Good point but I am not sure which part of the discussion you mean. I am not using NOOBS nor Raspbian but a self installed Arch Linux distribution. Since changing the disable_splash changes something it should be the correct file location.

Or have you meant the autoboot.txt?

Comment: I can't suggest a "solution", but can hypothesise a cause. I saw this 2 years ago when first using a Pi. I believe it is a magnified 4 pixel image, which is displayed when (or before?) the display is properly configured. It has nothing to do with `display_splash`. I think I "fixed" it by setting display mode in `config.txt`.

Comment: @Miliways: thx but as I understood that 4 pixel image should be the rainbow square https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md at disable_splash

Answer (score 2):

The upper right corner of the display shows a rainbow colored square, that's a sign of too little power.  Get a power supply that delivers more current to RPi.

See these articles for some help:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=82373
- https://i.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3wsya4/battery_power_showing_the_rainbow_square/
- http://raspberry2015.science/2015/12/10/new-raspberry-pi-model-2-review-unboxing-and-setup/#li-comment-296
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=95430&p=663594

Comment: It is not in the top right corner and permanent. It is fullscreen for a second or two on startup.

Comment: When running from a powered USB hub, my RPi showed that graphic, as you describe, full-screen for a brief moment on startup AND showed it in a smaller square after the RPi had been running.  Intermittent display: synonymous with power supply at/near threshold to show the indicator.  NOTE:  once adequate power was provided, intermittent connectivity problems with USB WiFI doodad evaporated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suppress the rainbow square (low power warning) you should edit config.txt:

```
sudo vi /boot/config.txt
```

And add the following entry

```
avoid_warnings=1
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. If I would have more reputation I would vote up. disable_splash=1 did it for us but with the mentioned unwanted side effects.